# Unity3d font with strikethrough

Tags: c#, fonts, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to have a strikethrough/linethrough (<strike>example</strike>) font in a `GUIText`?

I have searched all over and can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: You also might want to consider asking this at http://answers.unity3d.com or on the Unity support forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is outdated. You can now use TMP which allows for strikethrough.

Answer (score 11):

I was just trying to figure this out and found a different approach that gave me the strikethrough effect.

You can [combine unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Combining_characters) to create the strikethrough effect.

Here is the C# function that I used to convert some text to the unicode characters with the strikethrough.

```
public string StrikeThrough(string s)
{
    string strikethrough = "";
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        strikethrough = strikethrough + c + '\u0336';
    }
    return strikethrough;
}
```

And then to create a GUI Label with strikethrough text

```
GUILayout.Label(StrikeThrough("test"));
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible with just the standard GUIText feature of Unity3d. You might want to consider GL Lines or assets.

Comment: seems a bit over the top for what i need...but thank you anyway :)